# Stop auto-snapping to column in Excel 2015

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 2015, when scrolling horizontally through a sheet, snaps the view to the column start. Here's a GIF of what I mean:

[image: Excel column snap]

Is there any way to stop this from happening? It's incredibly annoying with larger columns. My version of Excel is 15.13.3.

Comment: No.  I'm pretty sure Excel always keeps the left hand border at the column edge so there's nothing you can do to show a half column on the LHS.